# disable firebase remote connection

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, privacy, firebase-analytics

In an Android app, google 'firebase analytics' is creating tracking connections despite being disabled.

Here's some logging:

`03-27 14:34:29.800 27902-27924/*** D/FA: Connected to remote service
03-27 14:34:34.802 27902-27924/*** V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
03-27 14:34:39.283 27902-27924/*** V/FA: Session started, time: 1743951
03-27 14:34:39.284 27902-27924/*** D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled`

The only play-services package I'm including is `auth`, which I need for federated login. Is there any way to get federated login without leaking user activity? Should I try `microg`?

Comment: How did you disable Analytics?  Using [this metadata in the manifest](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#permanently_deactivate_collection)?

Comment: @BobSnyder yes, I used the 'permanently disable' tag from the doc you linked

Comment: This log indicates events are not being sent: _Event not sent since app measurement is disabled_.  Are you seeing data at the Firebase Console that makes you believe that is not true?

Comment: @BobSnyder The logging suggests GMS code is doing a phone-home on app startup without my user taking any action. 'Session startup' says to me that a tracking ID is being created. So at least one event (app startup) is being sent. Am I misreading?